# Verificar Conexão com o banco e validar para o usuário

Tags: java, android, sql

Gostaria de saber o seguinte: estou tentando fazer uma aplicação que faz várias conexões com o banco de dados. Queria verificar sempre as conexões e caso a conexão não estiver disponível alertar ao usuário e encerrar o método em execução..

Por exemplo: Ao usar `Connection = DriverManager.getConnection()` e testar a conexão, se ela foi efetuada com sucesso continua o método, senão, para a execução e envia um alerta pro usuário!

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dando uma olhada na documentação do DriverManager, podemos ver que se algo der errado durante a execução de getConnection(), uma exceção do tipo SQLException será lançada.

Então, tente fazer o seguinte:

```
try {
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection();
    // continua a execução

} catch(SQLException e){
    // algo deu errado, mostrar o erro no Log de execução
    e.printStackTrace();
    // aqui você pode tratar a exceção e dizer ao usuário que algo deu errado
}
```

Recomendo que você dê uma olhada aqui também:
[Documentação DriverManager do Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/DriverManager.html)

Uma possível implementação com AsyncTask é a seguinte:

```
public class ConnectActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        connect();
    }

    private void connect(){
        new HandleConnection(this).execute();
    }

    public void getConnectionResponse(String response){
        if(response.equals("SUCCESS")){
            // prosseguir com o procedimento depois da conexão
            actionAfterConnection();
        } else {
            // exibir alerta de erro na conexão
            showAlertConnectionFailed();
        }
    }

    private void actionAfterConnection(){

    }

    private void showAlertConnectionFailed(){

    }
}
```

Acima temos a Activity que irá chamar a AsyncTask HandleConnection através do método connect().

Agora, a classe HandleConnection:

```
public class HandleConnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ConnectActivity connectActivity;

    public HandleConnection(ConnectActivity connectActivity){
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(connectActivity);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Carregando...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

        this.connectActivity = connectActivity;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("suaconexao");

            return "SUCCESS";
        } catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

            return "FAIL";
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String connectionResponse){
        super.onPostExecute(connectionResponse);
        try {
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            connectActivity.getConnectionResponse(connectionResponse);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

No construtor da classe HandleConnection pedimos uma instância da Activity ConnectionActivity, que é a classe que chama a AsyncTask. Já que temos a instância de uma Activity, podemos usar o seu contexto para criar um ProgressDialog, que é aquela janela que indica que uma ação está sendo executada e o usuário deve aguardar.

No método doInBackground da AsyncTask, verificamos se a conexão foi bem sucedida ou se algo deu errado. Se algo der errado, o bloco "catch" será chamado e o método retornará "FAIL". Caso contrário, retornará "SUCCESS".

No método onPostExecute, obtemos o retorno de doInBackground e passamos o valor para a Activity ConnectionActivity através do método getConnectionResponse(). Assim, o resultado da operação estará visível na Activity. Agora que você tem a informação da conexão, pode alertar o usuário caso a conexão falhe. Basta criar seu AlertDialog no método showAlertConnectionFailed() da Activity.

Comment: O catch não me deixa executar AlertDialog em uma thread de segundo plano.... mesmo q eu execute um trows dento do catch pra manipular ele depois... A questão é bem mais complexa que isso!!! Queria a ideia de uma validação que funcione em trheads, asynctasks e semelhantes, principalmente em execuções de segundo plano

Comment: Entendi seu ponto. Pra exibir algum tipo de Dialog em threads ou AsyncTasks, você precisará passar o contexto(Context) de uma Activity. Acredito que para conseguir pegar uma falha na conexão, se deva usar o catch com SQLException mesmo. Há outros meios de se obter uma resposta na classe da Activity para saber como proceder. Vou editar a resposta e você dá uma olhada.

Comment: beleza, aguardo o edit